# In Python, how to get typing right when using a class decorator?

Tags: python-3.x, class, pycharm, decorator, isinstance

This is my first attempt to make a Python decorator, and I humbly admit to drawing inspiration from a number of StackOverflow posts while doing so. When I scavenged the `__instancecheck__` method, the last two asserts stopped triggering, but now PyCharm's built-in linter isn't happy with the very last assert.

```
Expected type 'Union[type, Tuple[Union[type, Tuple[Any, ...]], ...]]', got 'Multiton' instead.
```

What is the root of the typing problem, and how can it be fixed?

*Addition,* after making the `__init__` change recommended by a commenter another warning surfaces.

```
Local variable 'instance' might be referenced before assignment.
```

```py
class Multiton(object):
    """ When init parameters match, reuse an old initialized object instead of making a new one. """
    def __init__(self, cls):
        # self.__dict__.update({'instances': list(), 'cls': cls})
        self.instances = list()
        self.cls = cls

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # make a key with the parameters
        key = (args, kwargs)

        # search for a matching old instance
        found = False
        for instance in self.instances:
            if instance['key'] == key:
                found = True
                break

        # if not found then create a new instance
        if not found:

            instance = {'key': key, 'object': self.cls(*args, **kwargs)}
            self.instances.append(instance)

        return instance['object']

    def __instancecheck__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.cls)


@Multiton
class YourClass:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number


yc_1 = YourClass(1)
yc_2 = YourClass(2)
yc_two = YourClass(2)

assert yc_1 != yc_2
assert yc_2 == yc_two

assert not isinstance(yc_1, Multiton)
assert isinstance(yc_1, YourClass)
```

Comment: Please don't do ``self.__dict__.update({'instances': list(), 'cls': cls})``. Just assign to the attributes.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the "error". Pylint has a few things to say and errors because of the unorthodox attribute assignment, but does not complain about types.

Comment: Thank you Mister Miyaga. When attempting the change you recommended, another warning appeared. I erred by assuming that PyCharm was using Pylint. I edited the original post accordingly.

Comment: I'm so sorry for misspelling your surname Mr. Miyagi.

Comment: You need to use a single ``for`` ``else`` loop instead of using a ``found`` flag to glue together separate ``for`` loop and ``if`` statement. PyCharm cannot understand that the *content* of ``found`` is related to the *presence* of ``instance``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The false warnings are PyCharm bugs which hopefully the fine folks at JetBrains will remedy soon.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38590
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-49966